# When does the item count reset for the Puzzle Ring?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have the Puzzle Ring in Diablo 3 which means that I have a cute little treasure goblin that runs around with me. He picks up and eats all the white items that I find and after a certain number (for me, it's 12 but I believe it varies) he poops out a rare or legendary item.

Depending on what I'm doing in the game, it seems like the item count resets differently. So what causes the item count to reset on the puzzle ring? Is it different depending on what you're doing - like regular game versus Rift?

Comment: What!? he drops items? I always used him to confuse my friends/party :X

Comment: @Brian yes, he drops items. On the Puzzle Ring it tells you how many white items he needs to pick up before he does so.